# How to pass the arguments to the function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a plot for this function but i was getting blank plot when I pass arguments.

```
def plot_fig(y, ylim=(), x=None, xlim=()):
    plt.figure()
    title = "v,w Vs Time"
    plt.title(title)
    color = ["b", "r"]
    if not x:
        for i in y:
            plt.plot(i)
    else:
        for i,j in enumerate(y):
            plt.plot(x, j, color=color[i])
    if ylim: plt.ylim(ylim)
    if xlim: plt.xlim(xlim)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Voltage")
    plt.legend(["V(t)", "W(t)"])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


xlim = (-0.5,1.5)
ylim = (-0.45,0.45)
time = np.linspace(-0.5,1,num = 100)
plot_fig(y=time, ylim=ylim,  xlim=xlim)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `plt.plot`, which is supposed to draw lines, but you only give a single point, so there is no line to draw.

You can spot the error if you specify the marker in the following line:

```py
if not x:
    for i in y:
        plt.plot(i, marker="o")
```

You get:

[image]

#### Some help

Below is an example of how it could looks like a litte improved.
I think you forget to give the computations for `v` and `w`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def main():
    xlim = (-0.5, 1.5)
    ylim = (-0.45, 0.45)
    num_points = 100

    time = np.linspace(*xlim, num=num_points)
    v = np.sin(time)
    w = 10 * np.cos(time)

    plot_fig(t=time, v=v, w=w)
    plt.show()


def plot_fig(v, w, t=None, ylim=None, xlim=None, ax=None):

    num_points = len(v)

    if t is None:
        t = np.arange(num_points)

    if not (len(t) == len(v) == len(t)):
        raise ValueError(
            "v, w, and x should have the same length, but found "
            f"{len(v)=}, {len(w)=}, {len(t)=}"
        )

    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax_v = ax
    ax_w = ax_v.twinx()

    (v_line,) = ax_v.plot(t, v, c="b", label="V(t)", marker="x")
    w_line = ax_w.scatter(t, w, c="r", label="W(t)")

    ax.set(
        title="V, W Vs Time",
        xlabel="Time",
        xlim=xlim,
        ylim=ylim,
    )
    ax_v.set_ylabel("Voltage")
    ax_w.set_ylabel("Watt")
    ax.legend(handles=[v_line, w_line], loc="lower center")
    ax.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With this you get:

[image: a bit better plot]

Comment: It has to be a kind of wave form I was expecting, if I want to pass these v = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 100)
w = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 100)

Comment: Yes it would be better, because your xlim was also off. Anyway don't set xlim and ylim first, set them once you sure you have a good plot and it is really needed for some reason.

Comment: How should I pass this I am still getting blank graph, V,W against time.

Comment: `np.linspace` doesn't returns a wave but a linear curve. I think you are missing computation for v and W vs time.